# How should I fold a shell script in vim? Is there an existing script or function for this?

Tags: folding, bash

I'm working on some shell scripts with a lot of:

```
# Parameter: images.0.created_at
if [ -z "$images.0.created_at" ]
then
        echo "images.0.created_at is empty"
else
        woostring="$woostring""--images.0.created_at=$images.0.created_at "
fi
images.0.created_at=""
```

And it would be really nice if I could get some folding here.

I'm thinking that at a bare minimum `if` and `fi` should be folded, but there must be more that would make sense.

What should I be folding, do any plugins exist for this, and if not; how should I get started?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35064131) and also [`:h folding`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#folding)